# How to get iTotalDisplayRecords value of initialized jQuery Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to check the `iTotalDisplayRecords` of a `jQuery` `dataTable`.  The data is already loaded and everything is initialized fine, but I'd like to pull the value of `iTotalDisplayRecords` from the `dataTable` object.  How do you do this?  What attribute or function of the `dataTable` object do you call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jons answer does only work with dataTables version 1.10.x and above. For other versions, eg 1.9.x use

```
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable();
var iTotalDisplayRecords = dataTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsDisplay();
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8CKjH/**

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`page.info()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info%28%29) API:

```
var dt = $('#table').DataTable();
var iTotalDisplayRecords = dt.page.info().recordsDisplay;
```

Comment: @davidkonrad: Yes, thanks for noticing. Edited to fix.